# argv[1] in an object's default constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to make a windows form c++ program, and everything works fine, but I cannot figure out how to use command line arguments in an object's default constructor

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include"Quotes.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
Quotes::Quotes()
{
    std::ifstream quoteList;
    std::string line, theme, author, birth, death;

    quoteList.open("quotes.txt");
    if (!quoteList.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "FILE NOT FOUND. QUITTING PROGRAM." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    for (int i = 0; !quoteList.eof() && i < 300; i++) //as _Quotes is an array of 300, limits loop to 300
    {
        getline(quoteList, line); //read in the quote
        getline(quoteList, theme); //read in the theme
        getline(quoteList, author, '('); //read in the author up to the opening parantheses for the year
        author[author.length() - 1] = ','; //replaces space after author's name with a comma
        getline(quoteList, birth, ' '); //read in the birth year up to the immediately following space
        quoteList.ignore(); //to skip the '-'
        quoteList.ignore(); //to skip the space after '-'
        getline(quoteList, death, ')'); //read in death year up to the closing parantheses
        quoteList.ignore(); // to skip the \n character
        Author tempAuthor(author, birth, death); //creates a variable author with appropriate information to be used for copying
        Quote tempQuote(line, theme, tempAuthor); //initialize a new instance of Quote with the info we need, then....
        _Quotes[i].copy(tempQuote, tempAuthor); //copy it over to _Quotes[i] and now it has the proper values
    }
    quoteList.close();
}
```

Sorry if that code is needless, this my first question, but how can I replace `"quotes.txt"` with `argv[1]`? Anything I try simply

Comment: You could use the Windows API functions to get commandline arguments at that point

Comment: Just pass it as an argument (i.e. don't use a default constructor)

Comment: Have `main()` store `argv` in some global variable, that your default constructor uses.

Comment: thanks for the ideas. 
@M.M Windows API functions? what do you mean?

Comment: The functions in the Windows API which retrieve the commandline arguments

Comment: Have you used: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`?

Comment: @m.m can you please give an example? CommandLineToArgvW and GetCommandLine are the only windows api functions that i've found but they are "undefined" when i try them.

Comment: @Amadeus I'm trying to figure out how to get the command line arguement wihtout sending it to main, as doing what you suggest wont send argv to the object I'm making. thank you though

Comment: If you mean that you get an undefined reference error, then you aren't linking required libraries. You'd need to post your code and error messages to get a more concrete answer

Comment: @M.M would my included libraries and headers be enough or would you like more? there are a few files and quite a bit of code i think.

Comment: Post a question according to the site posting guidelines

Comment: **You can't.** And if you find a way to, you still shouldn't. The correct and obvious solution is to give the constructor an argument.